# Sending login information via AJAX

Tags: ajax, security, authentication

Im using jQuery validate plugin and every form has multiple validation levels.

1. level is by validate plugin
2. level is:

   - data is submitted to site
   - I get a reply

     - if everything is ok -> JS redirects to url
     - if there is an error, it shows warnings

Now I wonder, is it safe to send login info via ajax? I know that with addons like firebug, I am also able to get all POST parameters with normal submit. But can somebody else interfere with ajax login request and steal precious data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it safe to send login info via ajax

You do use HTTPS, do you? If you do it's as safe as form submit.

Answer (score 1):

Are you issuing requests over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean someone else on the network, then see the earlier comments about HTTPs.

If you mean "can someone inject something into a page and steal the data", the answer is yes.  As you've observed, the user can install plugins which could do this; it's also possible that your page could be inadvertently be the target of injection via [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or some other flaw.